# Wrong css styles

Tags: html, css

How to enable content visibility? Why it is not visible?

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="categories"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

CSS styles:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 160px;
  background: #666;
}
.categories {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: #b6fd40;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5orwaoqr/3/).

Comment: Could you show your css? Also your div doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Next time please copy-paste your code into your question. It make life easier -.-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.content` element isn't being displayed because it has a height of `100%` (which is being calculated as `0` in this case). Since neither of the element's parent elements have a defined height, a height of `100%` is essentially `0`, since `100%` of nothing is also nothing.

You could set the height of the `html`/`body` elements to `100%`:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you don't want the element to have a height of `100%` of the `body` element, you could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract the height of the `.header` element as well:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2523zk75/)

```
.content {
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
  background: gray;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use [viewport percentage units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) such as `100vh`. Since this unit isn't always relative to the immediate parent element, you can use them without setting a height of `100%` on the `html`/`body` element:

For instance:

```
.content {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

or:

```
.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 160px);
}
```

Comment: Worth noting browser support for `calc()`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly It is supported in all modern browsers. Currently ~`81%` supprt total. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc Unless the OP is supporting IE8, this shouldn't be a problem.